# Cannot resize linear layout children in android react native module

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, react-native, android-layoutparams

[Full code here](https://github.com/sbaar/ResizableLLRN)

[Video of correct behavior in java and incorrect in react native here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxl2pkHHa3caUFUteHNmSUFlRnM/view)

I have modified a linear layout to respond to touch by resizing the left child while the right child takes up the rest of the space, simulating a horizontal scroll that can be 'opened' or 'closed' using the following code

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) leftView.getLayoutParams();
    //Log.d("ll","width " + newWidth);
    lp.width=newWidth;
    leftView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

In react native, touch is still calling this method and logging the expected values, but the size of the children is not updated. The only time it updates is when I switch the visibility to gone then visible again. Calling invalidate/requestLayout on the view from java or forceUpdate from js does not have any effect.

Is there some other code I need to call to invalidate and redraw the view? Is there a hint I need to give to react that this component scrolls or responds to touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RN android is indeed not updating children layout or visibility or adapter changes under most conditions. By inserting hooks into the custom view when an update is needed that will invalidate/requestLayout then call this code normal behavior is restored, mostly. There are still some cases where measurement does not happen like it does normally and I have to postDelayed Runnables that then cause this invalidation. Dealing with a node's parents may not be strictly necessary in all cases, but it is for some.

In View Manager

```
Method markNewLayout, getShadowNode;

public ViewManager(){
    super();
    if (markNewLayout == null) {
        try {
            markNewLayout = CSSNode.class.getDeclaredMethod("markHasNewLayout");
            markNewLayout.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try{
    if (getShadowNode==null){
        getShadowNode = UIImplementation.class.getDeclaredMethod("resolveShadowNode",int.class);
        getShadowNode.setAccessible(true);
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
public class MyShadowNode extends LayoutShadowNode {
@Override
public void markUpdated(){
    super.markUpdated();
    if (hasNewLayout()) markLayoutSeen();
    dirty();
}
@Override
public boolean isDirty(){
    return true;
}




 @Override
    protected CustomView createViewInstance(final ThemedReactContext reactContext) {

 view.setRnUpdateListener(new CustomView.RNUpdateListener() {
            MyShadowNode node;
            @Override
            public void needsUpdate() {
                view.requestLayout();


                Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if (node ==null){
                            try {
                                node = (MyShadowNode) getShadowNode.invoke(uiImplementation, view.getId());
                            }
                            catch (Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                            if (node != null) {
                                if (node.hasNewLayout()) node.markLayoutSeen();
                                ReactShadowNode parent = node.getParent();
                                while (parent != null) {
                                    if (parent.hasNewLayout()) {
                                        try {
                                            markNewLayout.invoke(parent,view.getId());
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        parent.markLayoutSeen();
                                    }
                                    parent = parent.getParent();
                                }
                                node.markUpdated();
                            }
                            Log.d(getName(), "markUpdated");
                    }

                };
                reactContext.runOnNativeModulesQueueThread(r);
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Any comments on my related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523334/reactrootview-in-native-layout-renders-0-height-on-2nd-launch/53560388#53560388) and my admittedly hacky solution?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and I found the answer on [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4990) old reported issue on react native's repo.

Add the following code in your custom layout and after that there is no need to even call requestLayout() or invalidate(). The changes are propagated as soon as you update your layout's LayoutParams. This solution is the same as the ones used in [ReactPicker.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/picker/ReactPicker.java) and [ReactToolbar.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/toolbar/ReactToolbar.java).

```
@Override
public void requestLayout() {
    super.requestLayout();

    // The spinner relies on a measure + layout pass happening after it calls requestLayout().
    // Without this, the widget never actually changes the selection and doesn't call the
    // appropriate listeners. Since we override onLayout in our ViewGroups, a layout pass never
    // happens after a call to requestLayout, so we simulate one here.
    post(measureAndLayout);
}

private final Runnable measureAndLayout = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        measure(
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        layout(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
    }
};
```

Comment: Upgrading from rn 33 to 38, i had to add this for the custom view group to work correctly. However, it is still neccesary to use the code from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing content of the layout one by one. May be one among those children has wrap content. You can use hierarchyViewer and uiautomatorviewer for it
Also think about weights also. If possible post the hierarchyViewer data.

Comment: To be clear, the right child has width 0dp weight 1 and the left view has an explicit width, starting at 50dp, changing with touch.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) leftView.getLayoutParams();
lp.width=newWidth;
leftView.setLayoutParams(lp);
leftView.requestLayout();
```

Above code will solve you problem.

Comment: this won't work. It's React-native. It blocks/ignores all requestLayout calls.