# ReactRootView in Native Layout renders 0 height on 2nd launch

Tags: android, android-layout, react-native

I am building a hybrid ReactNative app, an am launching a custom ReactNativeActivity with the ReactRootView added to a native layout.

This works fine the first time I launch the activity (see first screenshot), but **the second time I launch the activity (after hitting the back button to destroy the activity), the ReactRootView appears to have a height of about 10 pixels.**

Why is this?  What can I do to cause the render to have the correct height the second time?

Here's the code from my custom ReactNativeActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle properties = new Bundle();
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        properties = intent.getExtras();
    }
    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModulePath("index")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "CommutybleMobile", properties);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_react);
    LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.overallLayout);
    mainLayout.addView(mReactRootView);    
 }
```

Here's my layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:gravity="start"
     android:id="@+id/overallLayout"
     android:orientation="vertical">
 </LinearLayout>
```

Render after first activity launch:

[image: good render]

Render after hitting back and second activity launch:

[image: bad render]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is **not the best answer**, but I did manage to fix this by adding the following hack:

```
// Directly adding the react root view here (then changing to an embedded view) fixes a
// problem where the root view did not fill the space in the layout
setContentView(mReactRootView);
setContentView(R.layout.layout_react);
LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
mainLayout.addView(mReactRootView);
```

By first setting the content view to be entire ReactRootView, it appears to force a layout at full screen height.  So when it is then added later on to the mainLayout, it is already inflated at a reasonable height.

I did see some mention of this issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13613) and some solutions were offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934776/cannot-resize-linear-layout-children-in-android-react-native-module/39839405#39839405), but they were more complex than my hack above, and seemed to be almost as kludgy.

If anybody has a better answer to this, I'd love to hear it.